# Flutter for loop with json sublist

Tags: for-loop, flutter

I have a json which has a List value and I want to use this value under a gridview.builder, 
I tried that with a "for" it just taking first item of first list and repeat that according to lenght of related index, such as for first one (878, 878) second one (878, 878, 878) etc.
What am I missing?

My goal is getting related genre ids(I will turn them names later) beside related cards but now it looks like that;

[image]

My code and json sample are below;

```
body: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 1 : 2,
                          childAspectRatio: mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.05  : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-29),
                        ),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Stack(
                                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap:  (){
                                        setState(() {
                                          firstRun = true;
                                          String tempName;
                                          tempName = _name;
                                          String name = "imdbid=${snapshot.data.results[index].id}&language=${AppLocalizations.of(
                                              context)
                                              .translate(
                                              'lan_code')}@$tempName";
                                          saveNamedPreference(name).then((
                                              bool committed) {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                              MovieDetailPage.routeName);
                                          });
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                        height: 245,
                                        child: Stack(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Card(
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                                              elevation: 5,
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Container(
                                                    padding:EdgeInsets.only(right:10.0),
                                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                                                      radius: 40.0,
                                                      lineWidth: 5.0,
                                                      percent: snapshot.data.results[index].voteAverage/10,
                                                      center: Stack(
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                          Text(
                                                            snapshot.data.results[index].voteAverage.toString(),
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                              foreground: Paint()
                                                                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                                                                ..strokeWidth = 3
                                                                ..color = Colors.black,
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          new Text(snapshot.data.results[index].voteAverage.toString(),
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                              color: Colors.amber,),),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                      progressColor: Colors.amber,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    padding: mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? EdgeInsets.only(left:170.0, top: 10) : EdgeInsets.only(left:140.0, top: 10),
                                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text("${snapshot.data.results[index].title}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark  ? Colors.white : Colors.black,shadows: [
                                                            Shadow(color:Colors.grey,blurRadius: 0,offset: Offset(0,2)),
                                                          ]),maxLines: 3, textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
                                                        Text("(${snapshot.data.results[index].releaseDate.toString().substring(0,4)})",
                                                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark  ? Colors.white : Colors.black,shadows: [
                                                              Shadow(color:Colors.grey,blurRadius: 0,offset: Offset(0,2)),
                                                            ]),maxLines: 1, textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                                        Container(
                                                          width: 150,
                                                          height: 120,
                                                          child: GridView.builder(
                                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                                            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                              crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                              childAspectRatio: 2/1,),
                                                            itemCount: snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds.length,
                                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                                  for(var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds.length; i++, index++){
                                                                    print("${snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds.toString()}");
                                                                    return Text("${snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds.toString()}",);
                                                              }
                                                            return Container();}),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Card(
                                              elevation: 3,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? const EdgeInsets.all(6.0) : const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                child: Container(
                                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                  width: mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 140 : 120,
                                                  height: 245,
                                                  child:  ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                                    child: Image.network(
                                                      snapshot.data.results[index].posterPath != null ? "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${snapshot
                                                          .data.results[index].posterPath}" : "https://i.hizliresim.com/bbn0VB.jpg", fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: How can this work, you are using `index` in your `itemCount` but it is defined in your `itemBuilder`. Do you have another GridView or Listview that wraps this ? What do you want to achieve ? Do you want only all distinct `genre_ids` in your grid view ?

Comment: I edited my code, sorry I sent just a try, original one was as updated. when I work that print comman write list correctly I just want to add them to text widget. There is another griedview.builder around them for titles and images, full code it too long but that's relevant part. And I added an image too, I hope that would be more understandable.

Comment: Thanks that's clearer now, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to avoid confusion, name your `index` variable differently in both builders, then you can easily see that you can use both indexes instead of the `for` loop :

```dart
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(...),
  itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(...),
      itemCount: snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, indexGenre) {
        return Text("${snapshot.data.results[index].genreIds[indexGenre].toString()}");
      },
      return Container();
    );
  }
)
```

If you still want to use your loops in a more "programmative" way, then use the `GridView` default constructor directly (not the `GridView.builder` constructor) so that you can build the list of children "manually" :

```dart
GridView(
  children: <Widget>[
    for (var film in snapshot.data.results)
      GridView(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (var genre in film.genreIds)
            Text("${genre.toString()}")
        ],
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(...),
      )
  ],
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(...),
),
```

Note that this last solution requires Dart > 2.3.

Comment: That works thanks a lot, I was thinking more complex than I need, I think.